# locate element with selenim webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

i build a test that checks if elements are visible, my problem is that sometimes the test work, and sometimes not. i don't have an id locator in the code so i using the other locator that i have (Xpath, CSS selector) do you have an idea if the problem is because i don't have an id locator or maybe i need to use different ways to locate the elements by visibility
thanks
there is my code:

```
free = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html//div[@id='root']/div[1]/div[1]//div[")

if free.is_displayed():
    print("google data found")
else:
    print("google data not found")
time.sleep(1)


payable = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ItemCard__StyledCard-sc-1fl623o-3.MuiCard-root.MuiPaper")
if payable.is_displayed():
    print("found payable attractions")
else:
    print("not found payable attractions")
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: I'm guessing the page is dynamic and not static? If so you could try using a CSS selector.  I would need more information about what you are searching and what the page is doing to help you more however.

Comment: Is it ok if you also post the link of the website?

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes my page is dynamic i thought that maybe if i  scroll up and down to check the visibility it's going to work but it still does not locate the elements right.

Comment: unfortunately, i can't share the website it's not mine to share. but the page is a container with items and on the items, i have 2 different buttons  and i need to check by visibility if they exist on the page, sometimes i have to scroll up or down to see the elements but its not always work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should use Expected Conditions visibility explicit wait instead of `is_displayed()`. Something like the following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html//div[@id='root']/div[1]/div[1]//div")))
    print("google data found")
except:
    print("google data not found")

time.sleep(1)

try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ItemCard__StyledCard-sc-1fl623o-3.MuiCard-root.MuiPaper")))
    print("found payable attractions")
except:
    print("not found payable attractions")
```

Also, your XPath locator is bad. The `[` at the end of it makes it invalid locator.

Comment: thanks for the answer i check that out, about the Xpath you're right i didn't copy the same XPath its just for example.

Comment: thanks, it help me with the exception and improving the result. but i figure that i have to scroll between the element down and search the element and then up and search again and now my tses works good

Comment: Great! I'm happy I could help you. בכל בעיה עתידית אשמח לעזור שוב במידה ואוכל :)